# How a prostgres restore is made consistent

Tags: postgresql

When restored files will be consistent? At the beginning, when the backup starts or at the end when the backup was finished.

```
begin_offset=70184
begin_time=2022-04-06 15:46:36.812269+02:00
begin_wal=00000029000007D1000000AB
begin_xlog=7D1/AB011228

end_offset=3770760
end_time=2022-04-06 16:21:57.718591+02:00
end_wal=00000029000007D1000000AE
end_xlog=7D1/AE398988
```

Comment: I'm not sure it's clear what you are asking. Also - what sort of backup are you talking about - not a pg_dump backup by the look of it?

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you did a basebackup with copies of the wal files for the duration of the file backup operation.

https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/continuous-archiving.html

Assuming it was performed correctly at the end of the recovery the database will be current with the last transaction committed before the end time.